# Using an ABRecordRef @property triggers EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, ios, abaddressbook

I'm trying to implement some code that writes to a contact using code from [this Address Book guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/BasicObjects.html). I've declared a property in my ViewController.h:

```
@property ABRecordRef mABRecordRef;
```

Then I retrieve a record:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
      (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
```

At this point, I am able to successfully call `ABRecordSetValue`:

```
CFErrorRef anError = NULL;
bool didSet;   
didSet = ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, (CFStringRef)@"foo", &anError);
if( didSet )
{
    // ...
```

In this method, I also save the record:

```
self.mABRecordRef = person;
```

After some user action (in another method), I attempt to use this record in the same way:

```
CFErrorRef anError = NULL;
bool didSet;
didSet = ABRecordSetValue(self.ABRecordRef, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, (CFStringRef)@"foo", &anError);
```

But I get an error:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x...
```

Why is this? I am assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that my `ABRecordRef` isn't released between my first and second uses.

I've also tried saving off that record's UniqueId as well as `peoplePicker.addressBook`, then later on pulling the same record back, but I get a similar error.